# What is the correct value to return to the operating system upon the successful completion of a program?

Tags: c++

What is the correct value to return to the operating system upon the successful completion of a program

Answer (score 6):

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

from your `main()` function.

Alternatively, `std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` from just about anywhere in your program (it gets more complex if you have multiple threads/processes, obviously).

Note that on most platforms (and, in particular, POSIX), `EXIT_SUCCESS` has a value of `0`.  So `return 0` or `exit(0)` would usually work just as well.

Comment: @Kerrek: Could you provide a link?

Comment: Sorry, never mind. I think `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` have the exact same effect. I posted some quotes from the standard below. The point is that the default behaviour of `main()` is to return `0`, so I figure that `0` is the better thing to return explicitly from `main`, though it has the same effect as `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `main()` function should return `0` on success.

If you call `exit()`, you can call it with either `0` or the macro `EXIT_SUCCESS`. From the FDIS, 18.5.8, concerning `void exit(int status)`:

> If status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned.

To explain returning zero from `main`, here is 3.6.1.5:

> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`.